# Cannot open .chm file, gives "page cannot be displayed" error

Tags: chm

I downloaded a .chm file from some site, when i tried to open it im getting "page cannot be displayed" error.

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser, use properties/Unblock and don't open from network (or tell the registry that you trust your network path, which sometomes even works).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the file, click properties, and click unblock.

Comment: On clicking properties , I am not seeing option to Unblock. BTW I am using Windows 7

Answer (score 4):

Remove unwanted file name characters (such as "&" or others). Place it on your locally accessible folder on your hard disk (somewhere on the desktop) and see if the contents are displayed or not.

Answer (score -1):

Do you open the file across the network. Because there is a security issue in that case see:

http://www.helpscribble.com/chmnetwork.html